# 3com 4500 switch get some info with SNMP

Tags: switch, 3com, mib

I have 3com 4500 switch. I can got ram and CPU info with these:

```
1.3.6.1.4.1.43.45.1.6.1.1.1.3 - 1 Minute CPU AVG
1.3.6.1.4.1.43.45.1.6.1.1.1.4 - 5 Minute CPU AVG
1.3.6.1.4.1.43.45.1.6.1.1.1.2 - 5 Second CPU AVG
1.3.6.1.4.1.43.45.1.6.1.2.1.1.3 - Free Memory Remaining
```

But I could not find other information that I need, neither I could find MIB of 3com 4500.

I need:

- Bandwidth rating of ethernet interfaces
- Usage density of ethernet interfaces

And also some info from logs like:

- Collision
- Unexpected acts on ports

Can you give me some advices for these and from where can I find MIB of 3com 4500 switch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try to snmpwalk this tree iso.3.6.1.2.1.2

snmpwalk -v 2c -c YourCommunity HostnameOrIP iso.3.6.1.2.1.2

Answer (score 0):

1.3.6.1.4.1.43.1.16.4.3.24 This will show all interfaces.

Comment: Can you please explain your answer further?

Comment: Old question, still I'll answer in case someone stumbles here. This OID is not supported.

Answer (score 0):

The MIB files for theses switches can be downloaded from several sources.

Here is one : http://www.oidview.com/mibs/43/md-43-1.html

Unpack it in the right folder for your system and run snmpwalk with "-m ALL" to have the OIDs translated.

You will likely need to elaborate the data you get through snmp, to get the metrics you are looking for.

I would do this in perl, using the Net::Snmp module.